# Eloquent get rows where relation count equals column value

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

Assuming that i have `posts` table has field `minimum_comments` and have query scope in posts table to get the active posts doing something like this

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    $query->has('comments', '>=', 'posts.minimum_comments');
}
```

Putting in consideration that all relation already set up

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't test it, but try this:

```php
// Post.php

public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('minimum_comments', '<=', $this->comments()->count());
}
```

Then you can go and use it like this:

```php
// PostsController.php

public function myCoolFunction()
{
    $posts = Post::active()->get();

    // the rest of your logic..
}
```